# Get Child Gridview controls through Jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview, nested, selector

I tried to bind a Jquery datapicker event to a child gridview. It works fine with the parent gridview. However I couldn't get it work for the child gridview.
For the parent grid, this works fine:

```
 $('#<%=gvInvoiceClient.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtDOB').datepicker({...});
```

As the childgrid is rendered with different IDs that end with _gvChild, I used various wildcard selectors such as the following but couldn't get it work:

```
$('[id$=gvDetail]').find('input:text[id$="txtInvoiceEnd"]').datepicker({...});
$('[id*=gvChild]').find('input:text[id$="txtInvoiceEnd"]').datepicker({...});
```

here's the gridview

```
 <div runat="server" id="gvChild"> 
  <asp:GridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server">
     <Columns>                                          

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birthday" >
      <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblPeriodStartDt" runat="server" </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>                                                       
   <FooterTemplate>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                                        
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a class selector and it worked.   $(".calendar").datepicker({'''});

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" runat="server">
     <Columns>                                       
   <FooterTemplate>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB"  CssClass ="calendar" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                                        
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight typo in your selector.  If you have an outer element with `id` ending in `gvChild`, containing a text field with `id` ending in `txtInvoiceEnd`, you want:

```
$("[id$='gvChild']").find("input:text[id$='txtInvoiceEnd']").datepicker();
```